# Reference request: discretisation of probability measures on $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given a probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ with finite first movement, i.e.

$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|x|\mu(dx)~~<~~+\infty.$$

My concern is to approximate $\mu$ some $\mu_n$ that is countably or finitely supported. Of course, a generic way is to take such a $\mu_n$ concentrated on the grid $\{\vec{k}/n\}_{\vec{k}\in \mathbb Z^d}$. I wonder whether there exists more literature dealing with this issue, especially from the viewpoint of implementation. Many thanks for answers and comments.

PS: Thanks for the reply. To summarise, I'm interested in the $\mu_n$ such that:

(1) the computation of $\mu_n[\{\vec{k}/n\}]$ is tractable;

(2) the Wasserstein distance $W_1(\mu,\mu_n)$ is easy to estimate.

Of course, the quantisation approach provides a good upper bound for $W_1(\mu,\mu_n)$, but the computation of $\mu_n[\{\vec{k}/n\}]$ is not obvious. So my question is whether there exists some explicit "discretisation" of $\mu$ such that the "discretised weights" are easy to obtain?

Comment: See https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0981.31002 to this end.

Comment: Another approach would be to approximate the probability measure by sample distributions, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25048365).

Comment: [Cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is concerned with taking a probability measure of the form $n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$ by another one of the same form, but with *much smaller* $n$. Perhaps you can look into cluster analysis and check whether any of its algorithms generalize to the case where the original measure is some general (f.f.m.) probability measure $\mu$?

Comment: Generally, the answer may also depend on the form in which $\mu$ is given to you. Is it given in terms of its moments? Or can we assume that $\mu$ can be computed e.g. on polyhedra? Or on other kinds of sets?

Comment: You cannot talk about "tractable computation" of $\mu_n$ without first saying something about how $\mu$ is represented. Does it belong to some parametric family? Is it implicitly defined via some process? The computational answer will very much depend on that. The same applies to estimating the Wasserstein distance.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich Yes. Consider for example the most common case, i.e. $\mu(dx)=\rho(x)dx$. What is the general method to identify $\mu_n$ which may involve numerical integration?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to look for might be "quantization", see e.g. G. Pagès' review :

https://doi.org/10.1051/proc/201448002

Comment: Thank you very much for the literature. But what I'm interested in is slightly different from the quantization. Indeed, I'd like to find $\mu_n$ s.t. the computation of $\mu_n[\{\vec{k}/n\}]$ is tractable and the Wasserstein distance $W_1(\mu,\mu_n)$ is easy to estimate. Of course, the quantisation approach provides a good upper bound for $W_1(\mu,\mu_n)$, but the computation of $\mu_n[\{\vec{k}/n\}]$ is not obvious.